How to remember the index of st.selectbox accross pages?
I'm trying to keep the selection in my st.selectbox accross pages.
When returning to the first (main) page, the selection must be set as before.
Bellow is a simplifyied code: I still have a jump between to choices when I change the selection.
Does anybody have an idea? I'm using Streamlit 1.37.
import streamlit as st


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TITLE = "Demo Streamlit App"
    st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

    st.sidebar.markdown("Home")
    st.title(TITLE)

    # initialize session state
    ss = st.session_state
    ss.setdefault("execution", {})
    if "first_execution" not in ss.execution:
        ss.execution["first_execution"] = True

    if "edition_mode" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.edition_mode = "New script"  # default value

    form1, _ = st.columns([1, 1])
    with form1:
        choices = [
            "New script",
            "Import script",
            "Load a script",
            "Delete a script",
        ]

        # Edition mode
        selected_mode = st.selectbox(
            label="Edition mode : ",
            options=choices,
            index=choices.index(st.session_state.edition_mode),
        )

        st.session_state.edition_mode = selected_mode

        st.write("---")

    st.write("---")

    ### Switch to the right app
    if ss.execution.get("switch_page"):
        st.switch_page("pages/01_Editor.py")

Thanks !
